# Wifibot RS232 Serial Communication

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I am working on Robotic project with Wifibot Platform, this robot contains a **Windows Embedded Standard 7 OS**, to make things short, i want to send some bits from the **WES7** to a **DSPIC 3FF** via RS232 that controls the platform motors to make the robot move, i have developed a lot of programs using C#, but no results, is there any help from you guys.

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sendsendRS232
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();


        serial.PortName = "COM2";                
        serial.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(9200);
        serial.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
        serial.Parity = Parity.None;
        serial.DataBits = 8;
        serial.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serial.ReadTimeout = 200;
        serial.WriteTimeout = 50;

        serial.Open();


       if (serial.IsOpen)
       {
           byte[] hexstring = { 255, 0, 120, 0};
           foreach (byte hexval in hexstring)
           {
               byte[] _hexval = new byte[] { hexval };
               serial.Write(_hexval, 0, 1);
               Thread.Sleep(1);
           }
       }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does "no results" mean?  You tried something, and it failed to work? If so, can you show us the code.  There are a lot of serial port examples out there, e.g. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/SerialPort-brief-Example-ac0d5004

Comment: Have you tried all the usual things - same baud rate, same number of bits, same parity, same stop bits.

Comment: @iandotkelly i have edited the post, as i said i've tried a lot but this is my last try, what i mean by no results is that the program executes normally but the robot makes no move !!! ...

Comment: When you use the `new SerialPort()` constructor, you have to explicitly `Open()` the port after you set the options.

Comment: Have you tried exercising the robot using some other tools?  Can you be sure this is a problem with your program at all?  Does the robot come with its own test program you can try to use.

Comment: @Mitch ok that's true i've missed it here, but in my previous attempts i've done that, so thanks bro ...

Comment: @iandotkelly YES bro i've tested it with its own test program using wifi and it did worked just fine !!!!

Comment: Using wifi ......?   Did you mean wifi, and if so, that isn't really testing what your program is doing is it?  Have you tried a like for like example, using RS232?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @iandotkelly Yes am talking about real wifi, because the robot has a wifi card and for testing the robot you test it by your computer using wifi, but here am talking about a connection between the robot motherboard that has the CPU and the platform board that has the Motors to make the robot move by a DSPIC, they are connected via RS232 ...

Comment: To expand on @iandotkelly's point. Try this: Open up Hyperterminal (or something similar if on Win7), setup the connection (Baud/Parity/Stop bits) exactly as you have them in your code, then send the same 4 bytes that you are sending in your program using the terminal program. If you aren't familiar with using Hyperterminal or similar programs, you may need to do a bit of research. Something like this may help: http://techawarey.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/serial-port-communication-in-windows-7-using-hyper-terminal-and-putty/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've not got much to go on here, since we don't have the documentation for the device you are communicating with, so we cannot check the serial port settings, or whether the 4 bytes of data you are writing to the port are a correct message to send to it.

Since you have handshaking set to None, you might want to play with setting DtrEnable and RtsEnable to true, typical settings for a device that wants to send.

Another thing to check that might be an issue is the 'endedness' of the data.  If the data you are sending includes multi-byte values and one device is big-endian and another is little-endian, then the order the bytes are sent in is important, see the [following more detailed explanation](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/174.php).

Unfortunately it often comes down to experimenting with settings, or even using terminal programs like Hyperterminal or Putty to connect to the device and send the same data.

Just as an aside, when dealing with classes that implement IDisposable like the SerialPort does, I would use it within a using statement, e.g.:

```
using(SerialPort serial = new SerialPort())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

That way the connection will always be closed and disposed of when it goes out of scope.